# Getting formatting information of a cell in an Excel workbook in R

Tags: r, excel

I want to process an Excel Workbook (.xlsx or .xlsm) with multiple sheets using R. More specifically, I want to inspect the formatting (e.g. the background fill color) of each cell with data and do conditional processing based on that.

I have looked in several R packages for processing Excel files but couldn't figure out how to do this. The [openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx) package has the function *getStyles* which returns the list of all styles in the work book, but it is not useful for my purpose here since I want to read the style information of specific cells. The [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html)  package has similar functions which can find styles by name or data type, but the work book I want to process is prepared manually and doesn't have named styles as far as I know.

Is there a way to read style information of a single cell in an Excel Work book in R?

Comment: Have you tried the `tidyxl` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent) in the comment above, `tidyxl` package has functions to get all different styles used in a sheet, and to get cells to which each style is applied.